# Restricting the domain in a 3D pgfplot when the domain is a function of both x and y

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to set the domain of Y(\theta) and X(\theta) the following image

[image]

such that:

[image: $$(X(\theta),Y(\theta))\in[0,1]^{2}:X^{2}(\theta)\leq Y(\theta)\leq X(\theta)$$]

I have tried a lot of different suggestions and have struggled to implement a solution that works. The code for generating the image is:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={func(\x,\y)= (\x<-6*\y) * (0)   +   and(\x>=6*\y, \x<(1+1.2*\y)/2.2) * (\x)   +   (\x>=(1+1.2*\y)/2.2) * (1);}
  ]
    \begin{axis}[
      title={Illustration of Continuous Problem with $m=0.6$},
      view={-25}{30},
      ymin=0, ymax=1, ytick={0,0.25,0.5,...,1}, ylabel=$Y(\theta)$,
      xmin=0, xmax=1, xtick={0,0.25,0.5,...,1}, xlabel=$X(\theta)$, %x dir=reverse,
      zmin=0, zmax=1, ztick={0,0.25,0.5,...,1}, zlabel=$V_{E,a}$,
      ]
      \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.6]{func(x,y)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should make a drawing in 3d directly.  Your function is piecewise linear with linear conditions on the arguments... so forget about pgfplots.  Draw the three regions in the $xy$-plane and then you'll almost have it.  We can continue the conversation afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused as to what you mean?

Comment: Well, you have two lines that determine the function's behavior in the square $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$.  The lines are $6y = x$ and $5/11 +6y/11=x$.  By the way, I guess there is a sign error in your formula (\x<-6*\y).  You have to plot (a 2d plot) the square and the segments determined by these two lines in the square.  This is the first step.